# Variable not updating when onselectionchange updates

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that, when I select text in a textbox, should update two variables, `selection` and `selectionArray`. However, this is not the case. When I run the code, `selectionArray` is alerted, and it shows the original value of the variable, which is null. Why isn't the variable updating?

```
<textarea name="" id="textbox" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
var selection = null;
var selectionArray = null;

document.onselectionchange = () => {
    if(document.getSelection().toString() != '') {
    selection = document.getSelection().toString();
    selecionArray = [...selection];
    alert(selectionArray);

  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, you've got a typo: `selecionArray = [...selection];` (vs. `selectionArray`). If that's in your actual code and wasn't just an error during transcription for writing the question... wheulp, that's your answer.